# Changing Text Colors and ClickEvent of an Item inside a ListView(Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

The problem I am facing is I am unable to change the color of my Items inside the Listview to Black color.

My ListView's background (Which I've removed in order to see the items inside Listview) is supposed to be white background as well.

Inside my activity, I added my items using the adapter.add("Item"). Therefore I am lost trying to add an click event on that Item since it's a string.

Tried:

1. Changing properties directly in the axml file. Such as android:textColor/Foreground etc.
2. Adding a color.xml file and declaring it's color. Then calling that color variable to my listview component "android:thatcolorname"
3. Tried changing it from my coding inside my Activity. Such as mLeftItems.Foreground/TextColor etc. Even tried using android.graphics.color etc. It's not working for me.

My coding for my Listview is

```
        mDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.myDrawer);
        mLeftDrawer = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.leftListView);

        mLeftItems.Add("Add Device");
        mLeftItems.Add("Disconnect Device");
        mLeftAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mLeftItems);
        mLeftDrawer.Adapter = mLeftAdapter;
```

For my .axml file it's

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
<!-- The left navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/leftListView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#D2D2D2"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's okay, I've figured it out. By changing the code

mLeftAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mLeftItems);

to

mLeftAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.newLayout, Resource.Id.YourComponentID, mLeftItems);

Note that I've created a new axml layout to replace the pre-set SimpleListItem1 which by default is white color text. Inside that layout should consist a button or a text view. And from there, you may change the color you want of that button/textview component. Then you call the Id at Resource.Id.Xxxxxxx .

Hope this helps everyone in the future.